# Roll directories up to parent

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to roll data up that looks like this:

[image]

What I am looking for is this:

Y:\Data\FS02-V\Aetna\ETL                     |           Data, development files

So rows two and three being children of row one should roll up to the parent and the parent should show all file types contained.  I am working in sql server and this is the code that produces the source table:

```
      SELECT
         [MCL].[Category Description] As Category
        , [SF].[Directory] as Directory
        , CONVERT(BIGINT, [SF].[Length]) AS FileSize 
        , (SELECT MAX([Id]) FROM [dbo].[split](RIGHT([SF].[Directory],LEN([SF].[Directory])-1),'\')) AS [LevelsFromRoot]
    FROM [dbo].[FS02V_SourceFiles] [SF]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Extensions] [E]
        ON [SF].[Extension] = [E].[Extension]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[MasterCategoryLookup] [MCL]
        ON [MCL].CategoryID = [E].Category
    ORDER BY [SF].[Directory]
```

Table def:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FS02V_SourceFiles](
    [Length] [float] NULL,
    [Directory] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Extension] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Type] [nvarchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Extensions](
    [Extension] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Type] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Category] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Split function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @RowData nvarchar(max),
    @SplitOn nvarchar(5)
) 
RETURNS @RtnValue table 
(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    Data nvarchar(max)
) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    Declare @Cnt int
    Set @Cnt = 1

    While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)>0)
    Begin
        Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
        Select 
            Data = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@RowData,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)-1)))

        Set @RowData = Substring(@RowData,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)+1,len(@RowData))
        Set @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
    End

    Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
    Select Data = ltrim(rtrim(@RowData))

    Return
END
```

The path(Directory) is stored as nvarchar and it should be the driver to roll up to the parent.  I would assume the path needs to be split and my function is already doing something similar to get the path levels.  I think this would be easier in SQL with my raw data but at the end of the day I am going to be visualizing this data in tableau so if anyone knows if its easier to use sql for this before I feed it into tableau or just use tableau with my source data I would try that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this was simple:

Use abolve SQL to prepare the directories and group them with their respective files and then roll it up using Tableau and calculated fields.